# how the get_header and get_footer works without including any external file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a doubt regarding wordpress..I was learning to develop wordpress theme from scratch but I got some confusion...

If we want to call a particular function from another page in php then we have to put the "include(filename)" keyword but in wordpress if we call the "get_header" and "get_footer()" without the "include(filename)" then it still works ..

WHY its working..??

The following is my source code..

```
<?php

get_header();

?>

<h1>This is my index</h1>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Because this file is itself included from another file, and the required function(s) have already been declared in that parent file.

Comment: They are functions !! Look at what the function does !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Alex Howansky, the core functions are declared inside wordpress like `get_header()` and `get_footer()`. Those functions works like a chain.

**Here's how:**

1. Actual `get_header()` function is defined in `wp-includes/general-template.php`
2. `get_header()` calls `locate_template()` method to locate the template file
3. `locate_template()` call `load_template()` method,
4. `load_template()` method includes `require_once()` function to load the template file. `load_template()` and `locate_template()` methods are defined in `wp-includes/template.php`

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: where is the function definition of locate template,load template..and what about the do_action..? is it a user defined function or default function...?if it is user defined then where I will find the function definition ...?

Comment: `locate_template` and `load_template` are defined in `template.php` file and complete path is available in above answer. The `do_action` function is not user defined, it is the part of wordpress core functions.